# Whatsapp Cloud API - update profile image error: Please upload JPG image

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm following the docs on [updating whatsapp profile image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/business-profiles#update-business-profile).

I successfully uploaded the jpg image to the [Resumable Upload API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload), and got the file handle. But when using the file handle to update the whatsapp profile, I get a wierd error.

Request:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/PHONE_NUMBER_ID/whatsapp_business_profile' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -d '{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "address": "ADDRESS",
    "description": "DESCRIPTION",
    "vertical": "INDUSTRY",
    "email": "EMAIL",
    "websites": [
      "https://WEBSITE-1",
      "https://WEBSITE-2"
    ],
    "profile_picture_handle": "4::aW1hZ2UskdjfFEw==:ARb......"
  }'
```

Response:

```
{
"message":"An unknown error occurred",
"type":"OAuthException",
"code":1,
"error_subcode":3441012,
"is_transient":false,
"error_user_title":"Image type not supported",
"error_user_msg":"Please upload JPG image.",
"fbtrace_id":"ANhxQ6Pn-VLvrRSMtmFb24I"
}
```

I **AM** uploading a JPG image (tried multiple JPGs)!

Answer (score 0):

you have to call api this way to get file handle

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/{upload-session-id});
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = [
    "Authorization: OAuth $accessToken",
    "file_offset: 0",

];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('Your-File-Full-Path'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);    
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

and then call_user_func

```
 curl -X POST \
      'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/PHONE_NUMBER_ID/whatsapp_business_profile' \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
      -d '{
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "address": "ADDRESS",
        "description": "DESCRIPTION",
        "vertical": "INDUSTRY",
        "email": "EMAIL",
        "websites": [
          "https://WEBSITE-1",
          "https://WEBSITE-2"
        ],
        "profile_picture_handle": "4::aW1hZ2UskdjfFEw==:ARb......"
      }'
```

This Will Work Definitely.